# Clean install of python working environment

Tags: python, conda

I recently switched jobs and have the oportunity to create a clean programming working environment, cleaner and better than I used to have before. In my previous work I had some problems with running different versions of python next to eachother (or different versions of package) so I thought it would be a good idea to use Conda as a python install/package manager.

As an IDE I used to use idle because I find spyder a little cluttered, but I do however miss some functionality of a proper IDE and was thinking about switching to PyCharm for personal use and iPython (that is the same as python notebook isn't it?) for courses on python I will be giving.

What is the best way to do a very clean install? Do I install miniconda first and then python3.6 (and/or python2.7), pycharm, iPython? Or can I do this in a better way without getting to much clutter?

Comment: And you'll be teaching the courses?

Comment: Have you looked into using a virtual environment? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: @MadPhysicist, yes I'll be teaching the courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely suggest to go for miniconda or anaconda, as you already said yourself, since it allows you to keep different Python versions separated in different environments.

I cannot really give you advice on the editor to use, since I always use Spyder. It takes some time to get used to, but it very versatile and extremely useful when dealing with large and many Python scripts.